# JavaFX 2. How to stop or pause all animations?

Tags: javafx

I am working on creating a small game.

I use scene switching (scene with a main game's screen and scene with some Help information). So, I decided to use HashMap scenes and set all scenes there. And clicking the button "Help" causes the scene switching.

But I have an issue. I want to stop all animations on non-active scene and currently I just set scene as NULL. I know that it is very bad realization.

Could somebody help me and also explain how to pause or stop all animations on scene?

Setting scene on primaryStage:

```
public static void setSceneToStage(String sceneId, Stage stage) {

    SceneCollection.instance().clearCurrentActiveScene();
    SceneCollection.instance().setNewActiveScene(sceneId);
    stage.setScene(SceneCollection.instance().getScene(sceneId));
    stage.setTitle(sceneId);
}
```

Clearing non-active scene:

```
public void clearCurrentActiveScene() {

    if(activeScene != null) {
        scenes.get(activeScene).clearScene();
    }
}

public void clearScene() {
    scene = null;
}
```

Initialize new scene:

```
public void setNewActiveScene(String sceneId) {

    activeScene = sceneId;
    scenes.get(sceneId).init();
}

public void init() {
    scene = new Scene(new Pane(), 300, 300);
}
```

Comment: Do you use Timeines and Transitions for your animation? Both provide a pause() method. Thats asychronous but shall be fast enough.

Comment: @Jens-PeterHaack, yes, I use timelines and transitions. But, how could I pause all animations which I have in situation when there are 5 units with own Timeline? Maybe need to create List<Timeline> for all timelines in my game and execute pause() for all of them when I need it?

Answer (score 0):

I think your program has to have a structure that you can have access to all transitions at time, for example you can have ''TransitonManager Class'' and in that class you have a arraylist of transitions and then you can add this transitions to that in their constructors and then when ever you want , you can have access to all transitions and stop them.

```
class TransitionManger{
public static ArrayList<Transition> transitions = new ArrayList<>();
}

class CustomTransition extends Transition{
  CustomTransition(){
      TransitionManger.transitions.add(this);
  }

@Override
protected void interpolate(double v) {
  //todo do what you want
}
```

}

you can also use singleton design pattern for TransitionManger for better encapsulation.